# `Find` duplicates output

Tags: linux, unix, find, centos

```
$ find . -name some_file
./some_file
./dir1/some_file
./dir2/some_file
./some_file
./dir1/some_file
./dir2/some_file
```

Why?

Using CentOS release 5.7 (Final)
Linux version 3.0.52

Comment: What happens if you type `alias find`? What about `which find`?

Comment: `type -a find` (cc @CoryKlein)

Comment: @Kevin Awesome! Thanks for pointing that out. This could have been helpful to me several times in the past...

Comment: @Kevin `type: command not found`

Comment: ... What shell are you using? It's part of the single unix spec and works for me in `sh`, `zsh`, `bash`, `ksh`, `csh`, `tcsh`.

Comment: tcsh.  Perhaps it was never unpacked.

`$ whereis type`  
`type: /usr/share/man/man1/type.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1p/type.1p.gz`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had `find` aliased as `find .`

Thanks to @CoryKlein's suggestion of `alias find`.